# StackOverflow as a Flavors.me profile widget?

Tags: discussion

Is anyone else interested? I think it'd be nice to use for a profile/portfolio piece as a developer, and could probably be good for other IT people as well.

Here's a suggestion thread in their forums where you should chime in if it's something you'd want.

http://help.flavors.me/discussions/suggestions/42-stackoverflow-karma-recent-questions-answers-on-flavorsme

Comment: Looks like they're working on it from their end from that link you posted. I don't really think we need to do anything here.

Comment: I was just leaving a link here in case anyone else wants to chime in on the discussion and move them from "We'll consider it" to "yea, let's build this"